# What are the "framework binaries" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

IMPORTANT UPDATE: The question is about the **framework binaries**, which the dialog below mentions, and not about the dialog at all.

When I create an empty service application in Delphi, it warns me that *linkage to framework binaries* will have to be handled manually then.

I tried to google what these framework binaries are, but found nothing valuable except questions about what the dialog is.

Does anybody know what are these binaries, where they are, and how can I link to them manually?

Here is the text of the dialog:

```
---------------------------
Confirm
---------------------------
Unit "Unit6.pas" references the "Visual Component Library" framework, but the project currently has no framework assigned. Do you want to enable the "Visual Component Library" framework for this project?

(Not enabling the proper framework may require unit scoping, ambiguities, and linkage to framework binaries to be handled manually)
---------------------------
Yes   No   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

Comment: What is `Unit6`?

Comment: My guess is that the dproj is simply missing the framework. In my dproj file for a new service app I have `<FrameworkType>VCL</FrameworkType>` in the line after `<ProjectVersion>`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it's a standard auto-generated unit for service applications.

Comment: For me Tokyo will bring this dialog - and upon selecting 'No' will have FrameworkType=None - but XE7 will not - and have FrameworkType=VCL So David guessed right.

Comment: Imo, you have a strange attitude towards experts who are trying to help you.

Comment: @MartinA, my attitude is to the fact that people are trying to help me to solve the problem I didn't have, at the same time ignoring my real question, and even more, denying my tries to defend it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project, you have to choose whether to use VCL or FireMonkey in it, or neither.

A Windows Service Application requires VCL, but your project does not have VCL enabled, so it will not link in the VCL library into your service's EXE correctly. That is what the IDE is warning you about.

Comment: I know this. My question is about the **binaries**

Comment: I don't think that the question really is about the binaries. I think you are misinterpreting a slightly misleading message. A default Windows service app is self-contained. It doesn't need to be linked to anything. Set the framework type to VCL and there is nothing more to do.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, what makes you think so?

Comment: *Unit "Unit6.pas" references the "Visual Component Library" framework, but the project currently has no framework assigned.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So you think there are no any such binaries? Nor the way to link to them manually?

Comment: Nope. So, what is `FrameworkType` set to in your dproj file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172900/discussion-between-serhii-kheilyk-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: Telling me what my question is about and denying my tries to defend my point seem very strange to me.

Comment: What is frustrating is that you won't just set the FrameworkType to VCL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, but my question was not about the dialog and what to do with it. I wanted to know *what the framework binaries are*.

Comment: Probably something to do with other frameworks. It seems like a misleading message. If you would just set the FrameworkType to VCL and see what happens we might be able to confirm that this is what is triggering the message. Which would be useful information. Anyway, you seem only to care about linking to these binaries. When you find them link to them and be happy.

Comment: @SerhiiKheilyk The message is referring to the VCL's own packages (`rtl`, `vcl`, etc), which may be compiled statically into the final executable, or linked to dynamically so they are loaded at runtime from external `BPL` files.

Comment: I don't think the framework type influences runtime packages at all.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Of course it does. Other than the base `rtl` package, VCL uses different runtime packages than FMX does.

Comment: I know that. I mean the framework type setting in the dproj file. I don't think that changing it will lead to different runtime packages being linked. The runtime packages are determined by another setting.

Answer (score 1):

This dialog appears to be misleading. For a Windows service application, there are no framework binaries to be linked.

When you create your Windows service application you should select **Yes** when this dialog is shown, and the *FrameworkType* will be set to *VCL*. At this point you are good to go. You can build your service application and the generated executable file is self-contained. It can be deployed directly and has no further dependencies.

Comment: I got your point a long ago. The question is really about the binaries. Not about the dialog.
Well, downvoting indicates that's this was the wrong place to ask it.

Comment: This answer directly addresses your question about the framework binaries. For a Windows service application, there are no such things.

Comment: Does it mean they are for other app types? Which then?

Comment: Well, the other framework is FMX. So it likely refers to the linkage required for mobile apps. Not pertinent to Windows though.